# how to trigger and pass parameters to a job in a gitlab ci/cd via gitlab api?

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

can i pass parameters to a job via REST api call to a gitlab api, to trigger a specific job? I have a python script that runs as a part of the job and i would like to pass parameters to that script.
I would like to invoke that job via gitlab api. how would the request look like?

for example, based on the documentation , a curl command to trigger the pipeline looks like this

```
curl --request POST \ 
  "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/project_id/trigger/pipeline?token=**************&ref=main"
```

Question : so in my example below, i have a test-job1, which runs a python script, called mydumbscript.py and i pass in few parameters , $arg1 ... . can i pass this parameter via gitlab api and trigger this particular job?

I have set up a project in gitlab , say myproject and here is a sample .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Hello, $GITLAB_USER_LOGIN!"

test-job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    - python3 myproject/script/mydumbscript.py $arg1 $arg2 $arg3

test-job2:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "This job tests something, but takes more time than test-job1."
    - echo "After the echo commands complete, it runs the sleep command for 20 seconds"
    - echo "which simulates a test that runs 20 seconds longer than test-job1"
    - sleep 20

deploy-prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  environment: production
```

Comment: you absolutely can pass in variables via the curl api call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the gitlab documentation:

**You can pass any number of CI/CD variables in the trigger API call. These variables have the highest precedence, and override all variables with the same name.
The parameter is of the form variables[key]=value, for example:**

```
curl --request POST \
     --form token=TOKEN \
     --form ref=main \
     --form variables[UPLOAD_TO_S3]="true" \
     "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/123456/trigger/pipeline"
```

**CI/CD variables in triggered pipelines display on each job’s page, but only users with the Owner and Maintainer role can view the values.**

The key in example is the variable you will have defined in your pipeline when it starts running.   you can add multiple lines like the --form variables line.

fyi, this information and more can be found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/#pass-cicd-variables-in-the-api-call

Comment: thanks. for my use case , how do i target a specific job (test-job1, in my case ) and pass in arguments $arg1, $arg2 ... so forth

Comment: if you have --form variables[$arg1]="arg 1's value"  in the curl it will be available when that stage runs.   If you JUST want to run that stage you have to put conditions on the jobs so that only that stage runs when a particular variable is defined or has a specific value.   Hope that helps.   We use gitlab as our main CI/CD so I good bit of experience with how to craft those pipelines.

Comment: fyi, info here can help you specify when certain jobs run in a GitLab pipeline.   Remember, they are triggered by various conditions and that can be checked in the pipeline jobs to decided if a job is included or not.  https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html